# Using OData Filter Query to get open items with past due date from Sharepoint list using Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint, odata, power-automate

In my sharepoint list of items, I have a "Date Due" field, and a "Status" field. I'm trying to create a recurring flow that occurs once a week. It will grab all items that have a Status of "Open", and a Date Due of either that day or prior to it.

- Status contains either "Open" or "Closed".
- Date Due contains the due date of the item in a `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

#### This is my current flow:

1. Recurring Trigger of 1/Week.
2. Current Time
3. Get Items from a share point list.

   - So far for the filter I have `Status eq 'Open' and Date_x0020_Due le Date(@{body('Current_time')})`

     - `@{body('Current_time')` is the current time retrieved from step 2
4. I take those items and turn them into an HTML table
5. I send an email containing that html table.

Currently the filter for step 2 does not work. `Status eq 'Open'` is fine, however `Date_x0020_Due le Date(@{body('Current_time')})` does not work.

I'm guessing this is because OData cannot convert the DateTime object of Current Time into a Date object and is unable to compare them.

How can I change this filter so it returns items that have both a Status of closed and a Date Due of that day or prior?

#### Restrictions:

- I cannot change the names of any fields.
- I cannot change the data type of any field (ex. make Date Due a DateTime Type).
- I cannot add or remove fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow solved this.

#### My end flow looks like this:

1. Recurring Trigger of 1/Week.
2. Get Items from a share point list.

   - For the filter I have `Status eq 'Open'`
3. I use a filter array to remove the items that are past due.

   - The filter is `@lessOrEquals(ticks(concat(item()?['Date_x0020_Due'], 'T00:00:00Z')), ticks(utcNow()))`

     - [Ticks()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) Converts a timestamp into the number of ticks since January 01 1601 (according to flow at least, the documentation seems to be off in this case).
     - Using this I convert my date into a timestamp by using concat() to add time to the date.
     - I compare this to the current UTC time and see if it's less that the current date.
4. I take the filter array and input it into an HTML table.
5. I send an email containing that html table.